# appended answer as supplemental

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/740673/revisions

Надо бы перевести фразу

> appended answer 740765 as supplemental

[image: скриншот]

Сообщение получено при преобразовании ответа в правку:

[image: скриншот пункта меню]

Comment: Было уже такое. Отписывался на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300580/339911)

Comment: @alexolut, да, давно не фиксят...

Comment: а теперь и вовсе не дождёмся.